# Thevenin of DC circuits with inductors and capacitors

Tags: inductor, thevenin, laplace-transform

Can I use Thevenin's theorem for DC circuits containing an inductor or capacitor upon application of Laplace transform - bringing the entire circuit to the \$s\$ frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Laplace equations and their solutions will describe the transient and the steady state behavior of your circuit, provided you know the initial conditions of L and C.

Comment: is the solution for finding the equivalent Resistance (TH) the same for resistors ? (Turning off all power supply and simplifying the circuit for the total impedance)

Comment: But is this true if an L and/or C with initial conditions is within the Thevenin equivalent part of the circuit?

Comment: L-transform the circuit in the s space. C and L initial conditions comes in the circuit as Dirac's pulse voltage or current sources. Now you can use the Thevenin's theorem.